# Why are all tables sorted although only the first one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am creating a custom table for my application, which is sortable. The problem comes when i have multiple sortable tables.

The sorting of the last table works fine, but when I click on the first table header all the other tables also gets sorted.

All the sorting and filtering I did is inside the below library

```js
var IlForCustomTables = IlForCustomTables || {};
```

I just want to know why other tables are getting sorted when I click on the first table, and how I can solve this.

```js
var IlForCustomTables = IlForCustomTables || {};
IlForCustomTables = {
  //Basic Table
  BindTableDataBasic: function(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Body.length; i++) {
      $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').append('<tr class="tbody' + i + '"></tr>');
      for (let a = 0; a < Headers.length; a++) {
        if (a < startIndex)
          $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').find('.tbody' + i).append('<td></td>');
        else
          $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').find('.tbody' + i).append('<td>' + Body[i][Headers[a].replace(/ /g, '')] + '</td>');
      }
    }
  },

  BindCustomTable: function(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex, filter, sorting) {
    let filterInput = '';
    if (filter)
      filterInput = '<input type="text" class="filterInput" />';
    $('#' + DivId).append(filterInput + '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered"><thead><tr class="thead"></tr></thead><tbody class="tbody tbody_' + DivId + '"></tbody></table></div>');
    for (let i = 0; i < Headers.length; i++) {
      $('#' + DivId).find('.thead').append('<th class="SortTableHeader">' + Headers[i] + '</th>');
    }
    IlForCustomTables.BindTableDataBasic(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex);
    if (sorting)
      $('.SortTableHeader').click(function() {
        IlForCustomTables.CustomSorting(DivId, $(this).index());
      });
    if (filter)
      $('.filterInput').keyup(function() {
        IlForCustomTables.CustomFilter(DivId);
      });
  },

  CustomFilter: function(DivId) {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = $('#' + DivId).find('.filterInput');
    filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
    table = $('#' + DivId).find('.table');
    tr = table.find('.tbody').find('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      let found = false;
      for (let a = 0; a < tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length; a++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[a];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!found)
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  },

  CustomSorting: function(DivId, index) {
    const table = $('.tbody_' + DivId)[0];
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+1)'))
      .sort(comparer(index, this.asc = !this.asc))
      .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
  }
}

const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
  v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
)(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));


const TableHeader = ['Action', 'Id', 'Name', 'Age', 'Area Name', ' Work Experience'];
const TableHeader1 = ['Action', 'Id', 'Full Name', 'Current Age', 'Native Place', ' Work Experience'];
const TableData = [{
    'Id': '1',
    'Name': 'Ibrahim',
    'Age': '27',
    'AreaName': 'Wadala',
    'WorkExperience': '5'
  },
  {
    'Id': '2',
    'Name': 'Rohit',
    'Age': '30',
    'AreaName': 'Kalyan',
    'WorkExperience': '6'
  },
  {
    'Id': '3',
    'Name': 'Kunal',
    'Age': '32',
    'AreaName': 'Andheri',
    'WorkExperience': '7'
  },
  {
    'Id': '4',
    'Name': 'Yogesh',
    'Age': '38',
    'AreaName': 'Borivali',
    'WorkExperience': '8'
  },
  {
    'Id': '5',
    'Name': 'Varun',
    'Age': '36',
    'AreaName': 'Seawoods',
    'WorkExperience': '9'
  },
];

const TableData1 = [{
    'Id': '1',
    'FullName': 'Ibrahim S',
    'CurrentAge': '27',
    'NativePlace': 'Bangalore',
    'WorkExperience': '5'
  },
  {
    'Id': '2',
    'FullName': 'Rohit D',
    'CurrentAge': '30',
    'NativePlace': 'Pune',
    'WorkExperience': '6'
  },
  {
    'Id': '3',
    'FullName': 'Kunal D',
    'CurrentAge': '32',
    'NativePlace': 'Gujarat',
    'WorkExperience': '7'
  },
  {
    'Id': '4',
    'FullName': 'Yogesh R',
    'CurrentAge': '38',
    'NativePlace': 'Kankavali',
    'WorkExperience': '8'
  },
  {
    'Id': '5',
    'FullName': 'Varun S',
    'CurrentAge': '36',
    'NativePlace': 'Gujarat',
    'WorkExperience': '9'
  },
];
$(document).ready(function() {
  IlForCustomTables.BindCustomTable('ICGrid3', TableHeader1, TableData1, 1, false, true);
  IlForCustomTables.BindCustomTable('ICGrid4', TableHeader1, TableData1, 1, true, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ICGrid1"></div>
<div id="ICGrid2"></div>
<div id="ICGrid3"></div>
<div id="ICGrid4"></div>
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1szdw68/3/) for the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `click` handlers you select all `.SortTableHeader` and therefor the action for each div is bound to each header. You have to specify which header is meant:

```js
$('#' + DivId + ' .SortTableHeader').click(function() {...]);
```

**Working example:**

```js
var IlForCustomTables = IlForCustomTables || {};
IlForCustomTables = {
  //Basic Table
  BindTableDataBasic: function(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Body.length; i++) {
      $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').append('<tr class="tbody' + i + '"></tr>');
      for (let a = 0; a < Headers.length; a++) {
        if (a < startIndex)
          $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').find('.tbody' + i).append('<td></td>');
        else
          $('#' + DivId).find('.tbody').find('.tbody' + i).append('<td>' + Body[i][Headers[a].replace(/ /g, '')] + '</td>');
      }
    }
  },

  BindCustomTable: function(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex, filter, sorting) {
    let filterInput = '';
    if (filter)
      filterInput = '<input type="text" class="filterInput" />';
    $('#' + DivId).append(filterInput + '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered"><thead><tr class="thead"></tr></thead><tbody class="tbody tbody_' + DivId + '"></tbody></table></div>');
    for (let i = 0; i < Headers.length; i++) {
      $('#' + DivId).find('.thead').append('<th class="SortTableHeader">' + Headers[i] + '</th>');
    }
    IlForCustomTables.BindTableDataBasic(DivId, Headers, Body, startIndex);
    if (sorting)
      $('#' + DivId + ' .SortTableHeader').click(function() {
        IlForCustomTables.CustomSorting(DivId, $(this).index());
      });
    if (filter)
      $('.filterInput').keyup(function() {
        IlForCustomTables.CustomFilter(DivId);
      });
  },

  CustomFilter: function(DivId) {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = $('#' + DivId).find('.filterInput');
    filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
    table = $('#' + DivId).find('.table');
    tr = table.find('.tbody').find('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      let found = false;
      for (let a = 0; a < tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length; a++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[a];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!found)
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  },

  CustomSorting: function(DivId, index) {
    const table = $('.tbody_' + DivId)[0];
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+1)'))
      .sort(comparer(index, this.asc = !this.asc))
      .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
  }
}

const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
  v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
)(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));


const TableHeader = ['Action', 'Id', 'Name', 'Age', 'Area Name', ' Work Experience'];
const TableHeader1 = ['Action', 'Id', 'Full Name', 'Current Age', 'Native Place', ' Work Experience'];
const TableData = [{
    'Id': '1',
    'Name': 'Ibrahim',
    'Age': '27',
    'AreaName': 'Wadala',
    'WorkExperience': '5'
  },
  {
    'Id': '2',
    'Name': 'Rohit',
    'Age': '30',
    'AreaName': 'Kalyan',
    'WorkExperience': '6'
  },
  {
    'Id': '3',
    'Name': 'Kunal',
    'Age': '32',
    'AreaName': 'Andheri',
    'WorkExperience': '7'
  },
  {
    'Id': '4',
    'Name': 'Yogesh',
    'Age': '38',
    'AreaName': 'Borivali',
    'WorkExperience': '8'
  },
  {
    'Id': '5',
    'Name': 'Varun',
    'Age': '36',
    'AreaName': 'Seawoods',
    'WorkExperience': '9'
  },
];

const TableData1 = [{
    'Id': '1',
    'FullName': 'Ibrahim S',
    'CurrentAge': '27',
    'NativePlace': 'Bangalore',
    'WorkExperience': '5'
  },
  {
    'Id': '2',
    'FullName': 'Rohit D',
    'CurrentAge': '30',
    'NativePlace': 'Pune',
    'WorkExperience': '6'
  },
  {
    'Id': '3',
    'FullName': 'Kunal D',
    'CurrentAge': '32',
    'NativePlace': 'Gujarat',
    'WorkExperience': '7'
  },
  {
    'Id': '4',
    'FullName': 'Yogesh R',
    'CurrentAge': '38',
    'NativePlace': 'Kankavali',
    'WorkExperience': '8'
  },
  {
    'Id': '5',
    'FullName': 'Varun S',
    'CurrentAge': '36',
    'NativePlace': 'Gujarat',
    'WorkExperience': '9'
  },
];
$(document).ready(function() {
  IlForCustomTables.BindCustomTable('ICGrid3', TableHeader1, TableData1, 1, false, true);
  IlForCustomTables.BindCustomTable('ICGrid4', TableHeader1, TableData1, 1, true, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ICGrid1"></div>
<div id="ICGrid2"></div>
<div id="ICGrid3"></div>
<div id="ICGrid4"></div>
```